# MVC RedirectToAction usage in jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

So here's the thing. I have a controller like below

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
           return View();
      }

      public ActionResult Create()
      {
           return View();
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Create(string id, string name)
      {
           //... some WCF logic here.

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
}
```

My issue is with the post Create method. When it calls RedirectToAction(), I see in the web browser the Index page, but URL still says `http://.../Store/Create`, and if I press browser Refresh button, then instead of the Index view I get Create view. No AJAX is being used. Just normal `Html.BeginForm("Create", "Store", FormMethod.Post)`.
My routes are configured as such:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Any ideas? 0_0

**EDIT 1**

Perhaps I should point out that I use jquery mobile

**Edit 2**

My view, just in case.

```
@model WebApp.Models.StoreCreateModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Store", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Store</legend>

        @Html.Partial("_StoreEditFields", this.Model)

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" data-role="button">Back to list</a>
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Can you post your routes?

Comment: @Forty-Two if by routes you mean route configuration, then I've updated my question. That's the only line of code in that method

Comment: There is something else going on here that you are not including, because the code you've posted has nothing wrong with it.  Are you sure there isn't a code path that just returns the Index view in the Create method rather than RedirectToAction?

Comment: I'm reading on about jquery mobile. It seems that it does use AJAX behind the scenes. I just need to figure out ho to fix my issue now.

Comment: When you debug, is  `return RedirectToAction("Index");` actually  being hit?